# Is it possible to hide a servers location on the internet?

Tags: webserver, internet, geolocation

Can you make a server appear to be in another country and how would you do it?

Comment: This is basically what a TOR hidden service is.

Comment: @mti2935 - Not quite. A Tor hidden service is indeed hidden on the internet, but it does not "*appear to be in another country*", it has no identifiable location. The title and body of the question are not the same thing. If you want the appearance of being  in another country, then that's a VPN or VPS.

Comment: Your right and sorry. I ment what is asked in the title. I didn't know you could use a VPN on a server. I kind of thought I could but wasn't sure. Thank you very much for your time and response.